# Select from a text file

Tags: java, forms, file, extract

What can Ι use in Java instead of `Mid(m, 41,7)` in Microsoft Αccess in order to select a certain string from a text file?

For example: If Ι have a text `Abcdefghijkl` how to select from `c` to `g` only.

Comment: You can use `regex` or something like `str.substring(str.indexOf("c"),str.indexOf("g"))`. This is a pretty general question though.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `Mid` in MS Access is:

> Mid ( text, start_position, [number_of_characters] )

Therefore `Mid(m, 41,7)` means

> in String `m`, find characters starting at index `41` for `7` characters.

The java equivalent of this is to use the `substring` method, which has the following definition:

> substring(startIndexInclusive, endIndexExclusive);

Therefore, the equivalent method call would be:

`String mid = m.substring(41, 41+7);`.

---

> how to select from c to g only.

That is a different question, as the `Mid` method you provided doesn't do this. You'll need to expand your question to make it clearer what you're asking, if this is the behaviour you want to code in java.

Comment: I have a text file with  many records and I want some Data from it so i used microsoft access. Firstly i open the file. Then using Mid(41,7)&Mid (22,7)....to extract sections from it to an excel file it works but so slow  the text size is 15 MB